# If every subsequence of $x_n$ is unbounded, does $x_n$ diverge to infinity?

Tags: limits

Suppose $a_n>0$, limit of $a_nb_n = -1$, and $a_n$ goes to $0$, can we say $b_n$ diverges to negative infinity?

If the title question is true, then I can prove the above question.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 2):

For the question in the title:
No. If $x_n=n$ for $n$ even and $x_n=-n$ for $n$ odd the every subsequence is unbounded but $(x_n)$ oscillates between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$.

Answer for the second question: YES, $b_n=(a_nb_n)\frac  1{a_n} \to -\infty$.

Comment: Oh It's kind of typo. I mean that limit(a_n*b_n) = -1 when n goes to infinity. so I think b_n is not negative inverse of an...

Comment: Answer edited.  @Kyuwon Kim

Comment: Thank you very much!!